# angular-masonry displaying bricks in a single column after ngRepeat results are updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm experiencing some interesting behavior with angular-masonry. I load it as specified in their documentation:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchString" ng-keyup="search()" />
<div masonry='{"gutter" : 25}'>
    <div class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="result in results">
        <div>{{result.description}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I load $scope.results from an API call when the page loads and everything looks great... masonry renders all the bricks inline as you would expect. After I refresh the $scope.results from an API result set, the items render in a single column to the left of the page. The styling still looks great but I'm not able to utilize the full page width. I basically go from:

```
---- ---- ----
---- ---- ----
```

to:

```
----
----
----
----
----
----
```

Is there a way to tell masonry to recalculate the grid? or has anyone else found a good way to solve this problem? I've read a through a few questions and also looked at the github project but I can't seem to find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but this is working for me in a similar situation:

```
function refresh() {
    common.$timeout(function () { $scope.$broadcast('masonry.reload'); }, 100);
}
```

Call `refresh()` whenever your data source is changed/updated. It'll force masonry to recalculate the layout.

Comment: More details on my related problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27967781/how-to-fix-overlapping-bricks-with-angular-masonry

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
$('.grid').masonry('destroy');
```

just before set new data for repeat model.
it's helped me.